# Production impact due to large MSDB resulting from not configuring History Cleanup task

Tags: sql-server

I'm curious to know about the possible impacts in case MSDB grows big?

I need to provide this justification to the client as we failed to configure History Cleanup task while creating backup maintenance plan.

Comment: [This](http://sqlperformance.com/2015/07/sql-maintenance/msdb) blog covers the topic pretty well.

Comment: @BaconBits Thanks much Buddy! Yes, it was very helpful